# getting NSAttributedText UIKit additions to work

Tags: ios, ios7, nsstring, nsattributedstring

PLEASE SEE EDIT #1 BELOW WHICH ISOLATES ISSUE BETTER THAN ORIGINAL QUESTION

I'm trying to get the linkTextAttributes to work for UITextView and am getting pretty frustrated with it - this could be a straight Obj-C question. I'd rather not go to NSAttribtedString but might have to. I'm just trying to remove the underlining on a link. This works:

```
 textview.linkTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor]};
```

in making it yellow but I need to take out the underling. It looks like it should be like this:

```
 textview.linkTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor],
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyleNone};
```

but I get the following somewhat cryptic error:

[image]

I have tried:

```
      textview.linkTextAttributes = @{
                                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor],
                                      NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInt: NSUnderlineStyleNone]};
```

which removes the error but doesn't remove the underline. Any ideas on how to get this fixed? Or whether the above is the correct syntax?

### edit #1

so I'm trying to isolate the problem more into a new project. Here's the viewDidLoad from the main UIViewController; just trying to remove the underline:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITextView *textview= [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0F, 50.0F , 200.0f, 100.0f)];
    [textview setValue:@"here is my thinking <a href='http://www.some.com'>me</a>" forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
    textview.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
    textview.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
    textview.linkTextAttributes = @{
                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor],
                                    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)};
    [self.view addSubview:textview];
}
```

and the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
textview.linkTextAttributes = @{
                                NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor],
                                 NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)};
```

Comment: thx - I appreciate the answer and help but that didn't work for me. I am nervous I had a side effect so I isolated all the code into a viewDidLoad and provided screenshot above (and chanfged to blue so easier to see screenshot). Any ideas on how to get the underlining gone?

Comment: Ah, so you simply want the magical link to not be a link anymore?  Or do you want it to still be a link but just not obviously so?

Comment: Thx for response. So, we shut off the link in the original via            `textview.selectable = YES; textview.userInteractionEnabled = NO; ` and would just like to remove the underline (and bold it if humanly possible) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hoping other trying the same in Swift:

If You search "NSUnderlineStyleNone" OR " NSUnderlineStyleSingle" in ADC site, You will find only:

NSUnderlineStyleNone
Do not draw an underline.

Available in OS X v10.3 and later.

:(

So a **quick patch** for swift:

var underline : NSNumber = NSNumber(bool: false) // NSUnderlineStyleNone

OR

underline  = NSNumber(bool: true) // NSUnderlineStyleSingle

and later call it in this manner:

```
    let font = ....fontOfSize(18)!
    let attrString1 = NSAttributedString(
        string: "www.apple.com",
        attributes: [ NSFontAttributeName: font
            , NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()
            , NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: underline
        ]
    )
```